# mono C# multi-target 4.7.1 gives me netstandard 2.0 error

Tags: c#, mono, .net-standard

I have a Sample C# application that works under windows but fails on Mac OSX, that I try to build using 'dotnet build' but I get this issue:

> Program.cs(18,21): error CS0012: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [/Users/paolo/unity/industrial/Projects/PublisherSample/PublisherSample.csproj]

I am using the latest Mono 6.4 and targeting .NETFramework version 4.7.1

I added EnableFrameworkPathOverride to locate the 4.7.1 framework in Mono using:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- When compiling .NET SDK 2.0 projects targeting .NET 4.x on Mono using 'dotnet build' you -->
    <!-- have to teach MSBuild where the Mono copy of the reference asssemblies is -->
    <IsMac>$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))</IsMac>
    <TargetIsMono Condition="$(IsMac)">true</TargetIsMono>
    <!-- Look in the standard install locations -->
    <BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' == '' AND '$(TargetIsMono)' == 'true' AND EXISTS('/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono')">/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono</BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono>
    <!-- If we found Mono reference assemblies, then use them -->
    <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)/4.7.1-api</FrameworkPathOverride>
    <EnableFrameworkPathOverride Condition="'$(BaseFrameworkPathOverrideForMono)' != ''">true</EnableFrameworkPathOverride>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The first .NET Framework to be fully compatible to .NET Standard 2.0 is 4.72. So if possible you should target that. Though 4.71 has (partial) support, but it requires a large amount of additional dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn’t this also fail on Windows then?

Comment: You should try to use the NuGet package https://andrewlock.net/using-reference-assemblies-to-build-net-framework-libararies-on-linux-without-mono/. FrameworkPathOverride is not really helpful in every case.

Comment: That's it. That worked! Thanks!